# Disable button at the end of scroll in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, angular5, angular6

In my code I am scrolling div on button clicks. Here is my code.

[My Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhpphm)

I want to disable down button if the user scrolls to the end of div and vise versa. Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a customScroll directive for this..

I have created a demo on  **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-button-at-the-end-of-scroll-in-angular-6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-scroll.directive.ts)**. I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

> app.component.html

```
<button [disabled]="appScrollElement.disableBtn" (click)="onPreviousSearchPosition()">Up</button>
<button [disabled]="!appScrollElement.disableBtn" (click)="onNextSearchPosition()">Down</button>
```

> custom-scroll.directive.ts

```
import { Directive,HostListener,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomScroll]',
  exportAs:'appCustomScroll'
})
export class CustomScrollDirective {

    disableBtn:boolean=true;
    top:number;
    offSetHeight:number;
    scrollHeight:number;
    constructor(private eleRef:ElementRef){}

    @HostListener('scroll') onScrollEvent(event:Event){
        this.top=this.eleRef.nativeElement.scrollTop;
        this.offSetHeight=this.eleRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
        this.scrollHeight=this.eleRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
        if(this.top === 0){
          this.disableBtn=true;
        }
        if(this.top>this.scrollHeight-this.offSetHeight-1){
          this.disableBtn=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this

```
public onPreviousSearchPosition(): void {
    console.log(this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop -= 20);
}
```

and note that if in scrolled to the top then it will log 0 or a negative number,
so check the value each time and disable it if its <=0

Comment: can you plase show. When I am adding console.log line to function my scroll is not working. Can you please edit in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Based element height and current position, Disable and enable the button

TS

```
  public onPreviousSearchPosition(): void {
    this.scrollUp = true;
    this.scrollDown = true;

    if (this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop <= 20) {
      this.scrollUp = false;
    }


    this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop -= 20;
  }

  public onNextSearchPosition(): void {
    this.scrollDown = true;
    this.scrollUp = true;

    if (this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop >=
      this.scroll.nativeElement.offsetHeight - 20) {
      this.scrollDown = false;
    }


    this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop += 20;
  }
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="onPreviousSearchPosition()" [disabled]="!scrollUp">Up</button>
<button (click)="onNextSearchPosition()" [disabled]="!scrollDown">Down</button>
```

[Slack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpxkck?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to find out 2 things:

1. **Height of element `<p>`** by `const pHeight = document.querySelector("p").clientHeight;`
2. **scroll height** by`document.querySelector("p").scrollHeight`

so for finding **max scrolling height**, simply do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   const pHeight = document.querySelector("p").clientHeight;
   this.maxScroll = document.querySelector("p").scrollHeight - pHeight;
}
```

and disable buttons like this:

```
<button [disabled]="(scroll.scrollTop === 0)" (click)="onPreviousSearchPosition()">Up</button>
<button [disabled]="scroll.scrollTop === maxScroll"  (click)="onNextSearchPosition()">Down</button>
```

and add some styles to disable state of buttons, that provide in [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1akz9t)